# Creating multiple UIButtons but only the last visible

Tags: ios

I am creating multiple UIButtons inside a UIView. There are two nested loop, in order to create different groups of buttons, having different shape. The problem is that, only the last UIButton created is visible (and movable with the PanGestureRecognizer), even if the buttons should be inserted in different positions.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    int i, j;
    NSMutableString *backgoundImageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *barTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    sticks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.view = mainView;
    [mainView setNeedsDisplay];

    //create the bars
    UIButton *barra = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [barra addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [barra addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        backgoundImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Regolo%d%@",j,@".png"];
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            barra.frame = CGRectMake((SQUARE_SIZE * j), (SQUARE_SIZE * 2), SQUARE_SIZE, (SQUARE_SIZE * j));
            [barra setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backgoundImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [barra setTag:j];

            barTitle = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
            [barra setTitle:barTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [barra setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sticks addObject:barra];
            [self.mainView addSubview:(UIButton *)sticks.lastObject];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this code:

```
UIButton *barra = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
[barra addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[barra addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

inside your inner for loop.

You have a single object (UIButton *barra) whose properties you're changing inside a loop, so I think in the end all your buttons are stacked in the frame location of the last button (and with the final background, title, and tag values also), only the top-most is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You´re only creating one button.
Should be like this:

```
for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    backgoundImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Regolo%d%@",j,@".png"];
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        //create the bars
        UIButton *barra = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [barra addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [barra addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];


        barra.frame = CGRectMake((SQUARE_SIZE * j), (SQUARE_SIZE * 2), SQUARE_SIZE, (SQUARE_SIZE * j));
        [barra setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backgoundImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [barra setTag:j];

        barTitle = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
        [barra setTitle:barTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [barra setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sticks addObject:barra];
        [self.mainView addSubview:barra];
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should consider to rate the answers up and accept a question by clicking the checkmark. :)